# CodeIgniter HMVC urls not working properly with Twig template

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, twig, hmvc

I have a CodeIgniter 3.1 with HMVC extension, im using Twig as a template engine.

My problem is all my urls in the views inside the Modules return a strange value.

Example:

In the `Module/views/admin_template.html.twig` i call a controller from the `Dashboard` module

```
<a href="{{ base_url() }}{{'dashboard/index'}}">
```

this should be returning

```
http://mysite.dev/dashboard/index
```

instead is returning

```
http://mysite.dev/Template/mysite.dev/dashboard/index
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed `<a href="{{ base_url() }}{{'dashboard/index'}}">`

to

```
 <a href="{{ base_url }} {{ '/dashboard/index' }}">
```

and now it's working fine